# Select data to nested class with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model class like :

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public decimal Xcoor { get; set; }
    public decimal Ycoor { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have another class:

```
public class SectionCoordinateViewModel
{
    public SectionCoordinateViewModel()
    {
        this.Coordinate = new Coordinate();
    }
    public string SectionId { get; set; }
    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'm using LINQ to collect data from db:

```
var section = sectionService.getAll();
var data = from t in section
           select new SectionCoordinateViewModel
           {
               SectionId = "section_" + t.Id,
               //how to send data to Coordinate.Xcoor and Coordinate.Ycoor
           };
```

How to send them into Coordinate? Thank You

Comment: what is `t`? where you are going to get X and Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have `X` an `Y` properties in `t`. You need just initialize `Coordinate` object and use [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) to set `Xcoor` and `Ycoor` properties. Same as you did with `SectionCoordinateViewModel`:

```
var data = from t in section
           select new SectionCoordinateViewModel
           {
               SectionId = "section_" + t.Id,
               Coordinate = new Coordinate
               {
                  Xcoor = t.X,
                  Ycoor = t.Y
               }
            };
```

NOTE: Try to improve naming of your variables. E.g. instead of `section` you should use `sections`, because you get all sections from service. Not single one. Instead of `t` you can use `s` which stands for first letter of `section`. Instead of `data` you can use something like `models`. You also don't need `coor` suffix in properties of coordinate. Btw probably `Point` might be more appropriate name for `Coordinate` class.